# Convergence of R density() function to a delta function

Tags: r, kernel-density

I'm a bit puzzled by the behavior of the R density() function in an edge case...

Suppose I add more and more points with x=0 into a simulated data set. What I expect is that the density estimate will very quickly converge (I'm being deliberately vague about what that means...) to a delta function at x=0. In practice, the fit certainly gets narrower, but very slowly, as shown by this sequence of plots:

```
plot(density(c(0,0)), xlim=c(-2,2))
plot(density(c(0,0,0,0)), xlim=c(-2,2))
plot(density(c(rep(0,10000))), xlim=c(-2,2))
plot(density(c(rep(0,10000000))), xlim=c(-2,2))
```

But if you add a tiny bit of noise to the simulated data, the behavior is much better:

```
plot(density(0.0000001*rnorm(10000000) + c(rep(0,10000000))), xlim=c(-2,2))
```

Just let sleeping dogs lie? Or am I missing something about the usage of density()?

Comment: +1 Pretty interesting question. I would want to have an explanation myself.

Answer (score 1):

Per `?bw.nrd0`, the default bandwidth selector for `density`:

> bw.nrd0 implements a rule-of-thumb for choosing the bandwidth of a Gaussian kernel density estimator. It defaults to 0.9 times the minimum of the standard deviation and the interquartile range divided by 1.34 times the sample size to the negative one-fifth power (= Silverman's ‘rule of thumb’, Silverman (1986, page 48, eqn (3.31)) unless the quartiles coincide when a positive result will be guaranteed.

When your data is constant, then the quartiles coincide, so the last clause guaranteeing a positive result kicks in. This basically means that the bandwidth chosen is not a continuous function of the spread of the data, at zero.

To illustrate:

```
> bw.nrd0(rep(0, 1e6))
[1] 0.05678616
> bw.nrd0(rnorm(1e6, s=1e-6))
[1] 5.672872e-08
```

Comment: Amazing what happens when you RTFM :-) .  Nice detective work.

Comment: Also amazing what happens when you FFSME (Find ... Subject Matter Expert) :-) Thanks Hong!

Answer (score 0):

Actually (...tail between legs...) I now realize that my entire question was misguided. Being fairly new to R, I had instantly assumed that density() tries to fit Gaussians of different widths to the data points, optimizing both the number of Gaussians and their individual widths. But in fact it is doing something much simpler. It just smears out each data point, and adds up the smears to give a smoothed estimate of the data. density() is just a simple smoothing algorithm. So, yes indeed, RTFM :)

Comment: If you want normal mixture modelling, check out package mclust: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/